# copy+paste >8k rows in geany and gedit with default options no longer works, is there a copy/paste limit?

Tags: linux, gedit, geany

I've been editing manually some files with geany and things have been so far so good. I got recently one with >11k rows (5 columns), and I needed to copy (ctrl+c) >8k rows from it and paste (ctrl+v) (ie. replace) them into another file. The copy-paste process stopped working with this "big" file, so I assume there is a limit somewhere with it in geany. I received no error messages at all, so is there a limit? the same happens with gedit. I've not modified anything in both apps (ie. default options).

I prefer to do this with any of these applications, so any hint to get this working will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Describe "stopped working". Does copying work? Can you paste it somewhere else and get all rows? Or does even copying omit the rows? Can you paste more rows if copied from somewhere else? Which version did work and which doesn't anymore?

Comment: it does nothing, I copied the rows in both apps and tried to paste them somewhere else and those don't get pasted. But if I open the file in nedit, then copy them and then open another file with nedit and do the paste, then it works correctly, not sure why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, [nedit](http://www.nedit.org/) worked perfectly.

Comment: That's not an answer to your question :(